# Hacer invisibles controles en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

¿Hay alguna forma de esconder controles en javaFX de forma que éstos no ocupen espacio? He visto que en android es posible: `control.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
Lo que se me ocurre es esto:

```
control.setVisible(false);
control.setMinSize(0,0);
control.setMaxSize(0,0);
control.setPrefSize(0,0);
```

pero me conserva el espacio y me obliga a restaurar los tamaños originales una vez que los controles vuelven a ser visibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he creado dos métodos, uno para esconder un control y otro para mostrarlo:

```
void esconderControl (Control control) {
        control.setVisible(false);
        control.setManaged(false);
}
void mostrarControl (Control control) {
        control.setVisible(true);
        control.setManaged(true);
}
esconderControl (miControl); // hace desaparecer miControl de pantalla
mostrarControl (miControl);  // hace aparecer miControl de pantalla
```

El método `setManaged(boolean)` deja de gestionar el control, pero puede seguir apareciendo en la pantalla de forma inesperada en cualquier sitio dentro de su contenedor así que es imprescindible también utilizar el método `SetVisible(bolean)`

Answer (score 2):

Esta opción que intentaste, únicamente funciona usando el Android SDK :

```
control.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Para esconder un control en JavaFX, Puedes realizarlo con:

```
 control.setVisible(false);
```

o si no deseas que ocupe espacio tienes que removerlo:

```
contenedor.getChildren().remove(control);
```

Este es un ejemplo removiendo un botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El gráfico animado que pones no ayuda a aclarar para nada tu respuesta.

Comment: porque razón dices eso, es para mostrarte que removiendo la vista tienes algo similar a setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con el método `Node.setVisible(false)` que oculta el nodo, o puedes intentar con [setManaged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setManaged-boolean-) que va un poco más allá y deja de administrar el nodo, de esta forma no e realizan cálculos con el.

Puedes comprobar si esta administrado (Managed) con el método `isManaged()`